# How to simulate CPU scheduling(multilevel queue) using pthread library?

Tags: c, pthreads, cpu, scheduling

i wanna simulate multilevel queue scheduling using pthread library

i will make 3 ready queues.
The first queue has round-robin scheduling algorithm (time quantum = 2)
The second queue has round-robin scheduling algorithm (time quantum = 5)
The third queue has FCFS scheduling algorithm.

each queue has a thread that schedule processes.

queue priority : first queue > second queue > third queue

I wonder how to give priority for queues.
It's about synchronization using semaphore.

I hope that the higher priority queue's thread execute first.

how to do it?

Thanks to read.

Comment: priority Queue can be estableshed with heaps! max or min heap for example!

Answer (score -1):

Quoting Wikipedia [p_queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)
*"A **`priority queue`** is an abstract data type similar to regular `queue` or `stack` data structure in which each element additionally has a "priority" associated with it. In a priority queue, an element with high priority is served before an element with low priority*

*... a priority queue can be implemented with a heap or a variety of other methods such as an unordered array"*

The web is full of tutorials e.g.[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXdt1AHMB2o). you can implement the priority queue using heaps then determine where you have **critical sections** in the source code! Only then you should protect and prevent race conditions on these sections by lock these sections with mutex or simaphore or any other **o.s sync** mechanism.